# How do I get a list of Startup Projects in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

It is possible to start a debug session including multiple assemblies. While the dialog is simple to use for setup, it can be difficult to see at a glance which projects are selected without scrolling through the whole lot.

Is it possible to see only the projects that are set to start?

Don't mind if this is via Visual Studio itself or inspecting some sort of file or other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show a list of startup projects with the following command for [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) (Language: C#):

```
public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, GetStartupProjects(DTE).ToArray()));
    }

    System.Collections.Generic.List<string> GetStartupProjects(EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte)
    {
        if (dte != null && dte.Solution != null && dte.Solution.SolutionBuild != null)
        {
            System.Collections.Generic.List<string> result = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
            System.Array projects = dte.Solution.SolutionBuild.StartupProjects as System.Array;
            if (projects != null)
            {
                foreach (string s in projects)
                    result.Add(s);
            }
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the project names themselves without the (potentially) lengthy path names:

```
using System.Linq;

public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, GetStartupProjects(DTE).ToArray()));
    }

    System.Collections.Generic.List<string> GetStartupProjects(EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte)
    {
        if (dte == null || dte.Solution == null || dte.Solution.SolutionBuild == null) return null;

        var result = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
        var projects = dte.Solution.SolutionBuild.StartupProjects as System.Array;

        if (projects == null) return result;

        result.AddRange(from string s in projects select s.Split('\\') into parts select parts[parts.Length - 1]);

        return result;
    }
}
```